ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gemini' site:stackoverflow.com
Getting an error importing gemini in Google Colab
Hi All,
I am trying to work in Google Colab. Below is what I am trying to get started with.
import gemini
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery


# Initialize Gemini and BigQuery clients
gemini_client = gemini.Client()
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()

Error given as below:
      1 # Initialize Gemini and BigQuery clients
----> 2 gemini_client = gemini.Client()
      3 bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
      4 
      5 # Sample BigQuery table

NameError: name 'gemini' is not defined

I even tried pip install gemini and it does not install. Request your help on this.
Thank you.

I even tried pip install gemini and it does not install. Well, what does it do then?

Your error message show the problematic line as #2, rather than line 7 or so as it appears in the code you posted.  So you're not running the code you think you are.

Are you trying to use package for Google's Gemini AI? Because pip says this is for a genetic database thing.
https://pypi.org/project/gemini/#description

I'm going to guess you aren't trying to install the Gemini database framework linked by @tbold, and are instead trying to use one of Google's Gemini API SDKs, but it would help if you could clarify that.
If you want to use Google's Gemini API SDK the package is google.generativeai.
If are you trying to use the Vertex AI language model API the package is google.cloud.aiplatform.
